# I want to render string as script in ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

[This script is on render on page like html]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfZPm.png)I store the script in DB as string but i want to render in ejs as script in head tag.
and also custom css in style tag as <%= customCss %>
Custom CSS is working in Local but not in server.

```
"<script src="https://google.com/tag?id=11223"></script>" into
 <script src="https://google.com/tag?id=11223"></script>
```

i want to remove "" from start and end.
I passed <%= headerScript%> in  tag. But it's display in page as body.
I tried <% headerScript = headerScript.substring(0,headerScript.length); %> but not working.
How to render the whole code as a script.

Comment: Can you please try to rephrase the question? I am having some trouble understanding what you need.

Comment: I set one form that  store 2 fields as headerScript and CustomCss for Specific page.

I store as a string but in ejs  want use that header script in render work as script tag instead as "string" in body.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfZPm.png

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const script = document.createElement('script');
const srcRegEx = /src="(.*?)"/g;
const source = srcRegEx.exec('<script src="https://google.com/tag?id=11223"></script>');
script.onload = function() {
  alert("Script loaded and ready");
};
script.src = source[1];
// Append the script
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, Try using `<%- setup && setup.headerScritp ? setup.headerScritp : "">`
**ejs echo syntax** instead use of variable declare and use as `<%= headerScript>`.
this is working fine now.